# if/else not compare with null

Tags: sql, oracle, if-statement, plsql, null

in the end of this function compare

i make a test on `qty` value

if its = null it must return 0

else it return the qty as read from table

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION QTYDEPOT(
    id_pro IN NUMBER )
  RETURN NUMBER
AS
  qty NUMBER;
BEGIN

  .....

  IF qty =NULL THEN
    RETURN 0;
  ELSE
    RETURN qty ;
  END IF;
END;
```

the function work correct the probleme is always return `qty` with null values

so its never `return 0` when the table have a lot of `null qty` vales

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `IS` operator to compare with `NULL`

```
IF qty IS NULL THEN
```

Because using the normal operators like `=`, `<>`,  `>` and so on result in *unknown* when compared to `null`

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `=` by a `IS` :

```
IF qty IS NULL THEN
    RETURN 0;
ELSE
    RETURN qty ;
END IF;
```